# Could someone explain the tokenization process that's leading the whitespace creeping in here?

Tags: expansion

Here's a MWE that creates  spurious whitespace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand\aetest[2][\relax]{%%
  \def\aejunk{<#2>}%%
  \ifx\relax#1
  \else
    \def\aejunk{(#2:#1)}%%
  \fi
  \fbox{\aejunk\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}}%%
  }

\begin{document}

  \aetest[world]{hello}%%
  \aetest{ciao}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know how to fix this.  I just need to rewrite the `\ifx\relax#1` as

```
\ifx\relax#1%%
```

But I would have thought, since the only time this test is true is when `#1` is `\relax`, that the following whitespace would have been absorbed and the end of line comments should be unnecessary.  I assume there's something about the tokenization process I'm not understanding.  Could someone explain what's happening here that allows whitespace to creep in?

Comment: The space is added when you invoke `\aetest{ciao}`, since `\relax` tests true, and the space is then added, prior to the `<ciao>` fbox. You can test this by replacing the line-ending "space" with a `.%` and seeing when the dot shows up.  When you comment the `ciao` line, the dot goes away.  So that is its source, and indeed, as I said, it makes sense because the `\ifx\relax#1` test is true in the `ciao` case.

Comment: haven't tried it, but i think the space is the "unprotected" `#1` in `\ifx\relax#1`.  i'd reverse this: `\ifx#1\relax`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I reverse, I have larger headaches:  such as when `#1` is `aa`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tested something similar.  But where is the whitespace coming from.  As I understand expansion, `\aetest{ciao}` should expand to `\def\aejunk{<ciao>}%%\ifx\relax\relax....` and consequently I would expect that the second `\relax` will gobble up the trailing whitespace of that line.

Comment: @A.Ellett -- yes, wasn't paying attention.  i retract that suggestion -- *much* safer to add `%` after `#1`.

Comment: No, `\ifx\ifx\relax` does not gobble up additional white space *if true*, only if false.  Try `\ifx\relax\relax This is true\fi` to see that what follows a true condition is not gobbled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When TeX is absorbing the replacement text for a definition, it does no expansion whatsoever (unless you're using `\edef` or `\xdef`). In your replacement text you have

```
\ifx\relax#1
```

and the end of line counts as a space, because it is converted to a space during tokenization since it doesn't follow a control word. The space will not be ignored during expansion at macro usage time, because TeX isn't looking for `<one optional space>`, which it does after numeric constants or after the `=` in assignments where `=` is optional and some other cases where even entire strings of space tokens are ignored.

The fact that in the “no optional argument” case `#1` is replaced by `\relax` is completely irrelevant, because spaces are ignored after control words only during tokenization: space *tokens* that creep in after control words are not ignored.

Note also that in the definition you are doing, TeX actually does two `\def` commands. First it does

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\aetest\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\@protected@testopt
  \expandafter\aetest
  \csname\string\aetest\endcsname{\relax}%
}
```

and then

```
\expandafter\def\csname\string\aetest\endcsname[#1]#2{%
  \def\aejunk{<#2>}%%
  \ifx\relax#1
  \else
    \def\aejunk{(#2:#1)}%%
  \fi
  \fbox{\aejunk\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}}%%
  }
```

In the second definition, there's no trace of `#1` being `\relax` in the “no optional argument” case. But, as I said, this is irrelevant to begin with.

If you want a safe test for the “no optional argument”, use `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\aetest}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\def\aejunk{<#2>}}
    {\def\aejunk{(#1:#2)}}%
   \fbox{\aejunk\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}}%
}
```

so `\aetest{ciao}` and `\aetest[]{ciao}` would give different results.

On the other hand, if you just want to test if the optional argument is not supplied or it is empty, the usual

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
```

test is better.

Comment: Your detailed explanations are always very enlightening.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 6):

OK, I think I see what's happening.

When I define `\aetest`

```
\newcommand\aetest[2][\relax]{%%
  \def\aejunk{<#2>}%%
  \ifx\relax#1
  \else
    \def\aejunk{(#2:#1)}%%
  \fi
  \fbox{\aejunk\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}}%%
  }
```

There is, as of yet, no expansion of `#1` or `#2` yet to happen.  So, when `\aetest` is defined, the end of line character after `#1` gets tokenized.  Since once the space has been tokenized, it will not disappear later:  such as when

```
\aejunk{ciao}
```

gets expanded.

Comment: It was quite obvious from the beginning: `1` is not a control sequence, nor TeX is looking for a `<number>`, so the end-of-line is converted to a space. **Don't** use that test in order to see whether the optional argument hasn't be supplied: `[]` is much safer and the test can be `\ifx\hfuzz#1\hfuzz` or my preferred `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`

Comment: @egreg *obviously* ouch!  I forgot about the `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` trick.